# Mono/C#: A good GUI toolkit ? looks good on KDE?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gnome, kde-plasma

i am trying to get into developing for linux and i am a .net developer so i decided to give Mono a try. THe problem is that i am having problems trying to find a good gui toolkit.

I have chosen KDE over GNOME because its a little bit more pleasing on the eye.

I have looked here http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits

I get the sense GTK# is a good toolkit but its for GNOME. I know you can still run GNOME apps on KDE - but do they look nice ? probably not??

I would really appreciated any feedbakc from anyone who is doing the same or has done the same. I don't want to end up choosing the wrong toolkit and then have to change half way trhough.

Also i was hoping to do all my development on my Windows PC and then just pass it to linux when i am ready...  I presume this is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe Gtk apps in Qt mimic your Qt theme (at least, Qt apps do so in Gtk). You should install some Gtk apps from your distribution's repository to test this. Gtk# is the toolkit of choice for Mono on linux.

Comment: See my reply on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385753/is-qyoto-a-viable-platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qyoto is dead. I talked with the developer a while ago over IRC and he says that he will no longer contribute this project. But you should look at this: [gtk-qt-engine](http://code.google.com/p/gtk-qt-engine/)
GTK apps looks like native QT apps with this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that qyoto is dead ...
In [Qyoto C# KDE Bindings](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdebindings/csharp/qyoto/activity) last commit was 2012-01-08.

[Here](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/qyotosharptutorial/introduction/) you can found a nice tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it but this looks interesting: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Mar-16.html