# Is Qyoto a viable platform?

Tags: c#, .net, qt, qyoto

I don't ever really hear about Qyoto. My question is, is it still around and good to use? Would it be smart to use on one of my projects, or should I stick to gtk# or qt in another language? Are there any projects currently using Qyoto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last I checked, Qyoto was not stable on Windows. I'm currently using another .NET binding for Qt - qt4dotnet. Works fine but it you can't use Qt Designer with it and the API uses Java conventions because it's based on Qt Jambi. Also there is no integration between .NET events and Qt signals in qt4dotnet.

Comment: I had heard of qt4dotnet. The strange thing is that I heard it was less stable than Qyoto. Is this true in Linux? Is it nice to program with qt4dotnet? Is it actually stable? My attempts to write code with Qt Jambi did not end well, so I didn't really consider qt4dotnet. So, you would suggest qt4dotnet over qyoto?

Comment: @Patrick: Sure, I suggest qt4dotnet over Qyoto because qt4dotnet works well under Windows. Qyoto has a better API though, so it might be a better choice in Linux. I don't know of any projects using Qt with .NET, though. My experience with qt4dotnet has been that it's not nice to program with, but it's workable. So if you have reasons to use Qt together with .NET, qt4dotnet is good enough. Otherwise I'd stick with GTK#, WPF or something else.

Comment: @Patrick: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530841/mono-c-a-good-gui-toolkit-looks-good-on-kde

Answer (score 8):

I write a small cross platform app in .Net. I originally wrote it on Windows with a WinForms UI.  When I ported it to mono I found that the UI really suffered on Linux. In an effort to get a better Linux UI I rewrote the UI in GTK#. It is nice to have the designer, but GTK# is a terrible UI framework when coming from WinForms (never mind WPF). The fact that it is based off of a C framework really shows through. Many things show their procedural roots and it just doesn't feel very .Net centric. None of the controls understand the .Net Framework components.  So, for example, you cannot bind a DataTable to a GTK grid control. Also, the documentation is very poor.

Since I use KDE on Linux I've been looking into Qyoto for a long time. Recently I got my application loading a Qt UI. I designed it with Qt Designer and convert the .ui file to C# with the uics tool. This extra step is a pain to someone who's used to Visual Studio. Additionally, Qyoto doesn't really integrate with .Net either.  For example, the QT signal/slot mechanism is separate from the .Net event/eventhandler system. Again, the bolts and wires show through.

These and several other factors have forced me to move off of .Net for Linux GUI development. Again, since I use KDE, I will be sticking with Qt. My decision now is between Python and C++. Python is great for RAD, but I'm really looking for a great IDE and that is pushing me toward C++ (Qt Creator).

Comment: If the great IDE is the only point that made you adopt Qt Creator rather than PySide/PyQT, you can give a try to PyCharm.
I migrated a project from Qt/C++ (with Qt Creator) to PySide (using the PyCharm IDE), and I prefer the latter one by far. It's rapid, as you mentioned, and much more natural. I can't stand the .h files anymore and it would be hard for me to go back to Qt Creator...

Answer (score 0):

Update: Qyoto has recently been obsoleted, its successor is [QtSharp](https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp).

Its very confusing, looks like Qyoto was originally based off another project called QtSharp. Now the new project is also called QtSharp :/