# Where do I find tutorials for using Qt in MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, qt, monodevelop, qyoto

I remember using Qt for a C++ project I made a few years ago, and rather liked Qt particularly for how nice the application looked without requiring much extra work for cross-platform work, other than recompiling for Mac, Linux, and Windows. (Of course there's the binary packaging issue on each of the platforms also.).

I've looked at Qyoto (hmm no binary that looks like it works for Leapord, and it needs to use SMOKE), and qt4dotnet (last release July 2010, looks like it needs Qt jambi), and Qt# (seems extinct).

What are some good tutorials, or links to get me started on using Qt with MonoDevelop / C#?

Comment: ah, Georg, thanks for the edit. My bad. I knew that, I guess I did't bother to check. But do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: There is a list of toolkits here: http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits

Comment: Cheesebaron, thanks for documenting this. It is actually one of the sites that I researched before I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the actual answer, but I wouldn't recommend using Mono with any UI library. IHMO, for some server/console stuff Mono is OK, but not for UI.

I participated a project, which used Mono first with WinForms (which were very badly implemented on Linux) then with GTK. The idea of portability didn't pay off. You fill pretty soon bump against platform specific flaws.

I would recommend using Qt with C++. With the way how Qt allows you to minimize use of pointers you could learn the required subset of C++ very quick.

regards.

Comment: Thanks. I really liked working with Qt for my GUI based C++ applications, but I'm chasing up options for C# because I am in the midst of writing a C# application to get some experience for my next job which is going to require familiarity with C#. I like stetic/GTK#, but it seems incomplete after working with Qt, and Lazarus (fpGui, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

My experience with UI on Mono is very similar to Valentin's. I too found WinForms to be undesirable. I also found that neither GTK# or Qyoto really fit into the .NET framework well (see my answer to [Is Qyoto a viable platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385753/is-qyoto-a-viable-platform/7853353#78533))

However, to answer your question, when I ported my app to Qt I used the following tutorial:
[C# Qyoto tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/csharpqyoto/).

Again, I highly recommend using C++ for Qt development or WPF for C# development.

Comment: yes, I've seen the C# Qyoto tutorial, but as I mentioned, it looks like Qyoto is all but dead, so it didn't look like a place I wanted to invest much time into. Cheers

Comment: Ps,thanks for the link on your answer about the viability of Qyoto, thus the upvote for your answer.